# How to make a timestamp from two elements of an array in python?

Tags: python

I have a data file in the form of

```
Day      Time   Value
20100511,001012,8
20100511,001052,14
```

I load the file in a `SciPy` script with

```
data = np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",", usecols=(0,1,2))
y= data[:,2]
```

How can I make `x = timestamp` from the data given in the first two columns?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy using Pandas.  First, parse the CSV:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', skiprows=1, names=['Day', 'Time', 'Value'], dtype=str)
```

Then:

```
pd.to_datetime(data.Day + 'T' + data.Time) # ISO 8601 compact format
```

Which gives you:

```
0   2010-05-11 00:10:12
1   2010-05-11 00:10:52
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or, fancier, in a single step:

```
pd.read_csv('data.txt', skiprows=1, names=['Day', 'Time', 'Value'],
            dtype=str, parse_dates=[[0,1]])

             Day_Time Value
0 2010-05-11 00:10:12     8
1 2010-05-11 00:10:52    14
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use pandas, you can use `numpy.apply_along_axis`:

```
In [77]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0][2:-1] + x[1][2:-1], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), 1, data[1:])
Out[77]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 11, 0, 10, 12),
       datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 11, 0, 10, 52)], dtype=object)
```

Awkward string slicing because `np.read_txt` added an extra `b'` at the beginning and `'` at the end.